# How to optimize .Net rectangle drawing app MouseMove detection?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, optimization, mouse

I am recently working on a super simple drawing program in C# that can only draw rectangles. I want the program to highlight a rectangle when the cursor hover over it. But it will be slow because every time I handle the `MouseMove` event, I need to enumerate over all the rectangle the user drew and see if the point of the cursor is in the any of the rectangle. Can you tell me how to optimize the performance?

Comment: Are you using WPF or Winforms? How are you drawing the rectangles?

Comment: I am using winforms. I first draw the rectangles' fill using `FillRectangle` method, and then the border using `DrawRectangle`. When the cursor hover over the rectangle, I drew a thicker red border on top of the regular border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerating through the list of rectangles should be very fast so I don't see any problem with doing this in MouseMove. On the other hand redrawing of selected (hovered by mouse) rectangle is relatively slow so u should do it only if state of rectangle is changed (f e from 'hovered' to 'normal'). So call invalidate rect only if it is necessary and you will have no problems.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. But i would need to interate over the rectangles every time the mouse moves, so that event would come continously.

Comment: I did that many times :) CPU is not loaded at all. You can simply check that by yourself to be sure.

Comment: ...if you want you can of course check position of the mouse's cursor by timer one time per second f e. but it is unnecessary due to I described above.

Comment: Thank you so much. That is very comforting.